# What is the difference between ~ and ~* in nginx location regexes

Tags: regex, configuration, nginx, location

In the documentation for Nginx, I have notices that some location regexs look like

```
location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
```

and some look like

```
location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
```

Is there any difference betwenn these two regex forms (`~` and `~*`)

Comment: This is answered in the documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: here's the wiki link, kinda more tidy http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm not sure I would have spotted that in the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

~ performs a case-sensitive match

~* performs a case-insensitive match

You can also use !~, or !~* to mean "doesn't match..."